# GATE JAPE rule priorities not respected

Tags: nlp, grammar, gate

I have following text:

```
1 hwb wert: 330 kWh
```

In the first step, following mapping is tacking place:

`330 kWh` is mapped as: `Lookup.major = "unit"`

`hwb wert`is mapped as: `Lookup.major = "keyword"`

**The JAPE Rules:**

```
Phase: composedUnits
Input: Token Lookup
Options: control=appelt debug=true

Rule: TableRow
Priority:10
 (
  ({Lookup.majorType == "keyword"})
  ({Token.kind == punctuation})[0,4]
  ({Lookup.majorType == "unit"})
 )

Rule: ReversedTableRow
Priority: -2
(
 ({Token.kind == number})
 ({Lookup.majorType == "keyword"})
)
```

I can't understand why the `ReversedTableRow`-Rule is matched and not the `TableRow`.

Comment: Because the rules don't match the same text interval...

Comment: Btw `TableRow` cannot be matched on this text, because there is a colon (`:`) token in between the two Lookup-s

Comment: @dedek I updated the rule and still the other one is matched! If I remove the `reversedTableRow`rule, than the `tableRowRule`will be matched. What is now wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **appelt** priorities work only for the same regions of text (e.g. earlier match wins and longer match wins). Text consumed by a previous rule cannot be matched by a later rule...

From [the documentation](https://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:jape:priority):

> With the **appelt** style, only one rule can be ﬁred for the **same region
>   of text**, according to a set of priority rules. Priority operates in
>   the following way.
>
> 1. From all the rules that match a **region of the document starting at
>      some point X**, the one which matches the longest region is ﬁred.
> 2. If
>      more than one rule matches **the same region**, the one with the highest
>      priority is ﬁred
> 3. If there is more than one rule with the same
>      priority, the one deﬁned earlier in the grammar is ﬁred.

...

> Note also that depending on the control style, **ﬁring a rule may
>   ‘consume’ that part of the text, making it unavailable to be matched
>   by other rules**. This can be a problem for example if one rule uses
>   context to make it more speciﬁc, and that context is then missed by
>   later rules, having been consumed due to use of for example the
>   ‘Brill’ control style.

---

---

The rule `TableRow` can win as longer with following modification, note that I added the `:tableRow` label, which does not include the leading number token.

```
(
 ({Token.kind == number})?
 (
  ({Lookup.majorType == "keyword"})
  ({Token.kind == punctuation})[0,4]
  ({Lookup.majorType == "unit"})
 ):tableRow
)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. is then there a way to solve it, other than by separating the rules in different files -> different phases?

Comment: @Paul Do you want `TableRow` to be fired and `ReversedTableRow` not to be fired on the example text?

Comment: @Paul : You can also have multiple phases in the same file. Just move `TableRow` to a separate first phase and inside of the `ReversedTableRow`, you can check something like `{Lookup.majorType == "keyword", !TableRow}`